# Получаю все данные пользователя, добавляю/ удаляю данные массива cart и записываю его опять

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Адекватно ли таким образом делать, или есть более оптимальные методы?
Желательно узнать, что в этом случае предлагает mongoose

Comment: Если вопрос о mongodb (а не о конкретно js-логике), то эта инфа может быть полезна: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10290621

Comment: js логика тут не важна, спасибо за ссылку, сейчас прочту)